# how to achieve pagination in ftl(freemarker template)

Tags: css, pagination, freemarker

I want pagination for my table which goes like this

**prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 next**

the numbers **1 2 3 ...** will depend on the total rows in a table, like if a table has 38 rows and I want to show 10 rows at a time.
onclick of **1** first 10 rows should be shown, onclick of **2** next 10 rows should be shown, onclick of **3** next 10 rows, onclick of **4** the remaining 8.

I want the code in freemarker template. can anyone suggest how to approach this?[see pagination style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZy6B.png)

my table code is given below.

```
<#assign listOfOrders = EntityQuery.use(delegator).select("orderId").from("OrderItem").queryList()>

<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Order ID</th>
      <th scope="col">No. of Products Associated</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>      
         <#list listOfOrders as listOrder>
         <tr>
          <td>            
              ${listOfOrders[listOrder?counter - 1].orderId}<br>             
          </td>
           <td>             
               <#assign order =   listOfOrders[listOrder?counter - 1].orderId>
               <#assign count = 0>
               <#list listOfOrders as listOrder>
                  <#if order == listOfOrders[listOrder?counter - 1].orderId>
                    <#assign count = count + 1>
                  </#if>
               </#list>
               <a href="/xerus/control/ListOfProductsFtl?orderId=${listOrder.orderId}" id="view-text"> ${count} </a><br>                 
               <#assign  count = 0>              
          </td>         
        </#list>           
        </tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First, you should certainly check how `#list` works in the official documentation, because that you `#list` a sequence, and then still use `sequence[index]` to access its elements is suspicious. Frankly, I can't even follow how the template meant to operate.

Comment: Also, most of the work related to pagination is usually done on the query level. So usually  you have query which just counts the rows, and then a 2nd query that returns the the rows that are on the current page (so the query has an offset and a limit).